# google play services stopped error in google drive API in android app

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I have followed all the steps on android developer site to integrate google drive API in android application. I created Client ID on developer console with debug key as well as release key. But I am getting the error "Unfortunately, google play services has stopped.", when I test ed the app on real device. What should be the reason behind this? I have spent many hours searching on google for this issue, but can't find solution.

Does the Drive API setting is required for android app? Or should I put the Client ID in manifest file? I want to create folders and save data in it. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to test it correctly using the device emulator?

Comment: No, I tested it on real device. It works sometimes when we create new API key (Client Id) and then again fails when we do some changes.

Comment: The same story. Used github this example: https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart. Did not receive either 'onSuccess' or 'onFailure' events.

Answer (score 0):

In my case enabling Google Drive API in the developer console has helped:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com

I didn't see anywhere in the docs that it needs to be done and would not have any clue if didn't this discussion:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/issues/17